# How does Conv2d works when input's feature map is different from the kernel weight's input size?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, convolution

In this code "x" is an input to the convolutional 2D layer with 1 batch size, 256 both height & width size and 40 feature maps.

And, w is the weight for the convolutional layer, where the kernel size is (3x3), with depth of 10 and with 80 filters.

```
x = tf.random.uniform((1, 256, 256, 40))
w = tf.random.uniform((3, 3, 10, 80))
out = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w, strides = (1, 1), padding = 'SAME', data_format='NHWC')

output.shape

##############
OUTPUT: 

TensorShape([1, 256, 256, 80])
```

Here, this particular code works fine, where the output shape is (1x256x256x80). But Why?
Here, the input's feature map is not same as the depth, which I think it should be.

According to me, the weight should be of shape (3x3x**40**x80) instead of (3x3x**10**x80)
where the 3rd position value (i.e; in 2nd index which is 40) should be equal to the 4th position value (i.e; in 3rd index which is 40) of the shape of input.

Otherwise, how would the convolution operation will happen?

---

*** It also works fine for the weights with the shape ***

- (3x3x**1**x80)
- (3x3x**2**x80)
- (3x3x**4**x80)
- (3x3x**5**x80)
- (3x3x**8**x80)
- (3x3x**20**x80)

It seems like, it works with all the depth which divides 40.

Comment: It will always work when the input depth is evenly divisible by the filter depth.